# VB.NET String.Split method?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, split

I'm having some issues using the String.Split method, Example here:

```
Dim tstString As String = "something here -:- URLhere"
Dim newtstString = tstString.Split(" -:- ")
MessageBox.Show(newtstString(0))
MessageBox.Show(newtstString(1))
```

The above, in PHP (my native language!) would return something here AND URLhere in the message boxes.

In VB.NET I get:

```
something here
```

AND

```
: (colon)
```

Does the String.Split only work with standard characters? I can't seem to figure this one out. I'm sure it's something very simple though!

Comment: I have got it working by altering the line to:
Dim newtstString = Split(tstString, "-:-")

Although I am still unsure as to why String.Split wouldn't work properly.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx for all the overloads of string.split()

Comment: I'm coming here after investigating [String.Split is not removing the split text, only the first letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46330993/150605), and when I run your code `newTstString` is `{ "something", "here", "-:-", "URLhere" }`, which is what I would expect now that I know that `tstString.Split(" -:- ")` is functionally equivalent to `tstString.Split(" ")`.  The output listed in this question is what you would get if you ran `tstString.Split("-")`, although there would be a third element in the resulting array, `" URLhere"`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what you need to do, to prevent the string from being converted to a `Char` array.

```
    Dim text As String = "something here -:-  urlhere"
    Dim parts As String() = text.Split(New String() {" -:- "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

This is the `System.String` member function you need to use in this case

```
Public Function Split(ByVal separator As String(), ByVal options As StringSplitOptions) As String()
```

Comment: It should be noted that it does not convert the string into a `Char` array, rather, it uses the first character of the string and only passes that single character to [this `Split` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___). This is what happens when you let VB implicitly convert a `String` to a `Char`, and it is another reason to have `Option Strict On`.