# String.Split is not removing the split text, only the first letter

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, .net-4.5

What's going on here?

`issue.CallAction` has the following value:

```
"Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - Containers remaining changed to 0."
```

Splitting on it, like so:

```
issue.CallAction.Split("Containers remaining changed to ").ToList()
```

returns more than 1 string element (as expected in this case) but the elements are:

1. `Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 -`
2. `ontainers remaining changed to 0.`

It was my understanding that `Split` replaces the entire string that you're splitting yet it's only replacing the first letter.

What gives?

Here's a screenshot of the compiler being happy with a string separator. Note the absence of the angry red squiggle:

[image: Screenshot of the compiler happily allowing a string separator]:

Comment: I thought perhaps it was somehow passing the `string` as a `char[]` to the `String.Split(params char[] separator)` overload, but `"Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - Containers remaining changed to 0.".Split("Containers remaining changed to ").ToList();` fails to compile with error `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'` on .NET 4.7.  In hindsight, `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, but `.ToCharArray()` would be needed to make it a `char[]`.

Comment: Exactly my thought too because that's how it's behaving. I'm in .net 4.5.1 (I suppose I should tag that). I wonder if it's one of those things that they missed until 4.7? There's a big leap between 4.5 and 4.7.

Comment: I get the same compiler error if I build against .NET v4.5.1 on Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.5.

Comment: Wow, I get no such error. https://i.imgur.com/44By9jt.png

Comment: Aha!  You're using VB.NET.  I was compiling as C#.  If I compile as VB.NET it does successfully compile, and I see the same results you do.  IntelliSense shows that it is, in fact, calling the `params char[]` overload, which is why it's only splitting on the first character.

Comment: That's not very nice of it. It shouldn't be doing something other than what it's telling you it's doing. <sigh> VB, why?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is a case where C# pushes you into the Pit of Success ([1](https://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/), [2](https://i2.wp.com/csharpindepth.com/Files/PitOfSuccessAfter.png)).

Comment: Doh, looks like a duplicate of [VB.NET String.Split method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7919253/150605), anyways.  Although, the output they said they got in that question is not consistent with A) this question, and B) my output when I run their code, so while the solution is the same perhaps the question _is_ different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's treating the separator as a `Char`. At least in Visual Studio 2017/.NET 4.5,C# which is what I'm using, as well as [the current version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) there is no

```
string Split(string separator)
```

so you'd have to create an array of separators and populate the first one.

Try this:

```
        string s = "Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - Containers remaining changed to 0.";

        string[] separator = { "Containers remaining changed to " };
        string[] splitted = s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**EDIT:**

I haven't used VB in several years, so I had to do some re-learning here. The output of this sample program tells me that VB quietly coerces a `String` into a `Char` when a `Char` is called for:

```
Sub PrintAChar(c As Char)
    Console.WriteLine("Printing your character: '" + c + "'")
End Sub

Sub Main()
    PrintAChar("B")                ' Prints 'B'
    PrintAChar("Bob Was Here.")    ' Also prints 'B'
End Sub
```

See @Heinzi's important comment below for a best practice.

Comment: Huh, that... works. If you can figure out why there's no error, please let me know. It should be pitching a fit since the compiler seems fine with a string instead of an array. Thanks, btw.

Comment: Why there's no `Split( string separator )` bothers me to no end. Why it appears to be quietly converting your string to a char is a mystery for the moment. Stay tuned.  Providing a bit more context may help, given these things behave differently in different situations. Is this in a `.cs` file or a code behind? Which version of .NET and which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: .aspx.vb file, .net 4.5.1, VS 2013

Comment: In case you'd like to see it, it's telling me that there is a string separator overload: https://i.imgur.com/44By9jt.png

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` to disable this and other annoying implicit conversions.

Comment: @BobKaufman it's not converting it to a `char`. There's an overload for `Split` that takes an `IEnumerable<char>`(which means split on any of these), and `String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 4):

To get compile error you can turn [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076851/can-i-set-option-explicit-and-option-strict-on-a-project-solution-level).

To split by string in VB.Net, you can use [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split):

```
Dim result = Split(issue.CallAction, "Containers remaining changed to ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it interesting how the same code can appear to be both valid C# and VB.NET yet produce drastically different results?  I did notice the lack of a trailing semicolon but assumed it was just a copy-and-paste artifact.

Using the following code...

```
Dim text As String = "Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - Containers remaining changed to 0."
Dim list1 As List(Of String) = text.Split("Containers remaining changed to ").ToList()
```

...IntelliSense indicates that the [`String.Split(ParamArray() separator as Char())`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.split#System_String_Split_System_Char___) overload is being called ([the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b873y76a.aspx) includes the `ParamArray` modifier)...

[image: VB.NET IntelliSense for String passed to String.Split method]

Upon execution `list1` then contains the following:

```
list1(0) = "Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - "
list1(1) = "ontainers remaining changed to 0."
```

If you write it using this seemingly-equivalent syntax...

```
Dim list2 As List(Of String) = text.Split("C", "o", "n", "t", "a", "i", "n", "e", "r", "s", " ", "r", "e", "m", "a", "i", "n", "i", "n", "g", " ", "c", "h", "a", "n", "g", "e", "d", " ", "t", "o", " ").ToList()
Dim list3 As List(Of String) = text.Split("Containers remaining changed to ".ToCharArray()).ToList()
```

...IntelliSense indicates both `.Split()` calls are resolving to the same overload as above, yet the results for `list2` are very different...

```
list2(0)  = "Bl"
list2(1)  = ""
list2(2)  = ""
list2(3)  = "bl"
list2(4)  = ""
list2(5)  = ""
list2(6)  = "-"
list2(7)  = "W"
list2(8)  = "bS"
list2(9)  = ""
list2(10) = ""
list2(11) = ""
list2(12) = "-"
list2(13) = "9/20/2017"
list2(14) = "-"
list2(15) = ""
list2(16) = ""
list2(17) = ""
list2(18) = ""
list2(19) = ""
list2(20) = ""
list2(21) = ""
list2(22) = ""
list2(23) = ""
list2(24) = ""
list2(25) = ""
list2(26) = ""
list2(27) = ""
list2(28) = ""
list2(29) = ""
list2(30) = ""
list2(31) = ""
list2(32) = ""
list2(33) = ""
list2(34) = ""
list2(35) = ""
list2(36) = ""
list2(37) = ""
list2(38) = ""
list2(39) = ""
list2(40) = ""
list2(41) = ""
list2(42) = ""
list2(43) = ""
list2(44) = ""
list2(45) = ""
list2(46) = ""
list2(47) = "0."
```

...and the same for `list3`.  This is actually what we should have expected `list1` to be all along since it would split on any one of the characters in the passed `String`.

Why is this happening?  This is interesting to me, though I am not a VB.NET guy so perhaps this is common knowledge/pitfall.  If we take a look at [what the compiler produces](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) we see this:

```
Dim text As String = "Blah blah - WebSite - 9/20/2017 - Containers remaining changed to 0."
Dim arg_13_0 As String = text
Dim expr_0E As Char() = New Char(0) {}
expr_0E(0) = "C"c
Dim list As List(Of String) = arg_13_0.Split(expr_0E).ToList(Of String)()
Dim arg_31_0 As String = text
Dim expr_26 As Char() = New Char(31) {}
RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(expr_26, fieldof(<PrivateImplementationDetails>.B46FB904AE74F7001A264BB77882D707B0E9ECC7).FieldHandle)
Dim list2 As List(Of String) = arg_31_0.Split(expr_26).ToList(Of String)()
Dim list3 As List(Of String) = text.Split("Containers remaining changed to ".ToCharArray()).ToList(Of String)()
```

That is, in the case of `list2` it is passing a `Char` array consisting of all of the `Char`s in `"Containers remaining changed to "`, yet in the case of `list1` it is passing a `Char` array consisting of only the first `Char`, `"C"c`!  Talk about different results from similar-looking code...

I can't find a single document that connects all of these dots, but, basically, `String` will be [implicitly converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/implicit-and-explicit-conversions) to `Char()`, which calls the [`CChar` conversion function](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions#cchar-example), which returns only the first `Char`.  Thus, the following four lines are equivalent:

```
Dim list1a As List(Of String) = text.Split("Containers remaining changed to ").ToList()
Dim list1b As List(Of String) = text.Split(CChar("Containers remaining changed to ")).ToList()
Dim list1c As List(Of String) = text.Split("C").ToList()
Dim list1d As List(Of String) = text.Split("C"c).ToList()
```

Comment: That's absolutely crazy that it would do that. Most of the time, C# and VB are equivalent enough that you don't need to know or care about this. Thanks for the details as well as the compiler code site.