# string.split()(1) removes first character

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, split

I am running into an issue when i split a string on "_Pub" and get the back half of the string it removes the first character and I don't understand why or how to fix it unless i add the character back in

```
 strFilePath = "/C:/Dev/Edge/_Publications/Ann Report/2013-2016/2016 Edge.pdf"

 Dim relPath = strFilepath.Split("_Publications")(1)
 lb.CommandArgument = relPath
```

returns Publications\Ann Report\2013-2016\2016 Edge.pdf

Comment: Please show the exact input and output

Comment: And if you do `(strFilepath.Split(“_Publications”))(1)`?

Comment: Tried that and get the same output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET String.Split method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919253/vb-net-string-split-method)

Comment: ...So add the character back in? You know exactly what it was...

Comment: I can yes i just didn't know if that would have been considered the "right" thing to do

Comment: It's better than the alternative (basically using `IndexOf` and `Substring` to roll your own string splitter).

Comment: just trying to understand why it doesn't work as i expected it to

Comment: Because most people, when they use a delimiter, don't want all their data polluted at the beginning or end with it. So when you split, you get the data on either side of the string/character (or between delimiters), but not the delimiters themselves..

Comment: If you turn on Option Strict you would see what is going on. String.Split takes a Char(). You did not supply this explicitly so .Split took the first Char in your string as the splitter. It does not return the splitter as part of the resulting strings.

Comment: What you have as a delimiter is not a string array "string()" but a regular string. You need a string array to use a string as a delimiter. otherwise it takes the first char of your string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Assuming that `strFilePath` is intended to represent a path, it should not start with a "/" and the path delimiter in Windows is "\", not "/".

Answer (score 3):

What you have as a delimiter is not a string array "string()" but a regular string. You need a string array to use a string as a delimiter. otherwise it takes the first char of your string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

try this

```
Dim relPath = strFilepath.Split(new string() {"_Publications"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton I know. I was lazy ;)

Comment: Good catch! This is something that's easily overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to get the part of the path starting at some directory. Splitting the path might not be such a good idea: imagine if there was a file "My_Publications_2017.pdf" in a directory "C:\Dev\Edge\_Publications". The split as you intended in the question would give the array of strings {"C:\Dev\Edge\", "\My", "_2017.pdf"}. As has been pointed out elsewhere, the String.Split you used doesn't do that anyway.

A more robust way would be to find where the starting directory's name is in the full path and get the substring of the path starting with it, e.g.:

```
Function GetRelativePath(fullPath As String, startingDirectory As String) As String
    ' Fix some errors in how the fullPath might be supplied:
    Dim tidiedPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath.TrimStart("/".ToCharArray()))

    Dim sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
    Dim pathRoot = sep & startingDirectory.Trim(New Char() {sep}) & sep
    Dim i = tidiedPath.IndexOf(pathRoot)

    If i < 0 Then
        Throw New DirectoryNotFoundException($"Cannot find {pathRoot} in {fullPath}.")
    End If

    ' There will be a DirectorySeparatorChar at the start - do not include it
    Return tidiedPath.Substring(i + 1)

End Function
```

So,

```
Dim s = "/C:/Dev/Edge/_Publications/Ann Report/2013-2016/2016 Edge.pdf"
Console.WriteLine(GetRelativePath(s, "_Publications"))
Console.WriteLine(GetRelativePath(s, "\Ann Report"))
```

outputs:

> _Publications\Ann Report\2013-2016\2016 Edge.pdf
>   Ann Report\2013-2016\2016 Edge.pdf

Guessing that you might have several malformed paths starting with a "/" and using "/" as the directory separator character instead of "\", I put some code in to mitigate those problems.

Answer (score -1):

The Split() function is supposed to exclude the entire delimiter from the result.  Could you re-check & confirm your input and output strings?

Comment: @chillzy is correct - the whole delimiter is removed, but providing a single string to the function means it is treated as an array of char delimiters.